# How to hide shopping cart until 1 item is added?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide a shopping cart that appears in the navigation until at least 1 item is added to it -- then it can be visible.

This is the HTML and jQuery code I have but it's not working. Any help would be great!

```
<li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap wsite-nav-cart wsite-nav-5" id="" style="position: relative;">
    <a href="#" class="wsite-menu-item" id="wsite-nav-cart-a" style="position: relative;">Cart (<span id="wsite-nav-cart-num">0</span>)</a>
</li>

// Cart hidden until 1 item added

function checkCart() {
  var item = $('#wsite-nav-cart-num');
  if (item.length < 1) {
    $('#wsite-nav-cart-a').hide();
} else {
    $('#wsite-nav-cart-a').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think length is doing what you think it does please check https://api.jquery.com/length/. 
You should use text() or html() to get span value and then check it.
Something like this:

if (parseInt($('#wsite-nav-cart-num').text()) > 0)

Comment: Ok, the text() makes sense compared to the length, thanks for that. I reworked the coding to this, but still to no avail:

function checkCart() {
  var item = $('#wsite-nav-cart-num');
  if (item.text == 0) {
    $('#wsite-nav-cart').hide();
} else {
    $('#wsite-nav-cart').show();
}

Comment: item.text should be item.text()

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but I'm just not getting it to work. Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out and here is the jQuery code that works. Thanks again!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   var x = $("span#wsite-nav-cart").text();

   if (x == 0){
     $("#wsite-nav-cart-a").hide();
    } else {
     $("#wsite-nav-cart-a").show();
   };    

});
</script>
```